# Servicestack - run built-in clients on the .net client profile framework

Tags: servicestack, .net-client-profile

Is it possible to run servicestack's built-in clients on the .net client profile framework?
When i change the target framework property in the project settings to ".Net Framework Client Profile" and try to compile i get the following message: the namespace ServiceClient does not exist in the namespace servicestack.

We use servicestack services to send exception reports. We use the JsonServiceClient and feel really comfortable with it. We could change the target framework - but then we have to check all installations for the availability of the full .net framework.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [package contents](http://preview.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common/3.9.25/Contents) of the latest `ServiceStack.Common` package there seems to be no -client version included (See *Common Framework and Profile Targeting Examples* under [NuGet - Creating and Publishing a Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package)).

You should either change the target framework the full profile or pull the code from [ServiceStack's GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) and *try* to build it for client profile yourself. The downside of this is that you will loose Nuget's awesome update features...

You could off course file an issue at GitHub for the guys maintaining ServiceStack to add a client profile version of the framework, but I guess that there's a good reason for why it's not there already.